# Растягивание объекта сверху вниз

Tags: c#, unity3d

Есть объект `ПУСТЫШКА` в нем есть объект `РЕЗИНКА` и объект `ИГЛА`.
На `РЕЗИНКЕ` весит скрипт:

```
public Transform cube,
                 rubber;
```

Я не могу понять, как растягивать объект, что за расчеты делать и как мне при растягивании, двигать `ИГЛУ`за `РЕЗИНКОЙ`, при этом, чтобы когда достигло `КУБА`, чтобы все остановилось?

Я пробовал прибавлять к `РЕЗИНКЕ`:

```
transform.localScale += new Vector3(0, 0.00001F, 0);
```

И у `ИГЛЫ`:

```
transform.position -= new Vector3(0, 0.001f, 0);
```

Игла опускается, но резинка махом растягивается вверх и вниз, а надо только в низ...

И ко всему еще нужно, чтобы только до куба, вообще не могу врубиться.
Я думаю, что нужно делать через:

```
Vector3.Distance(transform.position, cube.position);
```

Но не понимаю, как мне только вниз растягивать и что рассчитывать.

Пытался сделать так:

```
Vector3 size = transform.localScale,
pos = transform.position;
size.y += 0.001f;
transform.localScale = size;
```

Она растягивается вверх и вниз.
Никак не получается сделать, чтобы только вниз.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Объект скейлится относительно центра. Тебе нужно двигать центр вместе с скейлом.

```
needle.transform.localPosition -= new Vector3(0, -Time.deltaTime, 0);
rubber.transform.localPosition = new Vector3(0, needle.transform.localPosition.y*0.5f, 0);
rubber.transform.localScale = new Vector3(1, needle.transform.localPosition.y, 1);
```

Comment: Сильно удивлюсь, если это сработает. "объект" в юнити вообще никак не скейлится, скейлится полигональная сетка путем передачи специальной матрицы, которая, в случае Unity это scale составляющая tranform матрицы. Чтобы объект скейлился так, как задано в вопросе, нужно создать свою мешу со смещенным центром.