# Время на растягивание объекта ризинка

Tags: c#, unity3d

Не совсем правильно растягивается, как сделать более плавно и что нужно поправить или добавить?

```
IEnumerator Fade() {
    Vector3 scale = transform.localScale;
    while((dis = Vector3.Distance(rubber.position, cube.position)-1.5f) > 0.5f) {
       yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.1f);
       rubber.transform.localPosition -= new Vector3(0, 7.8f * Time.deltaTime, 0);
       transform.localPosition = new Vector3(0, rubber.transform.localPosition.y, 0);
       scale.y += 0.002f * Time.deltaTime;
       transform.localScale = scale;
    }
    print("Success...");
}
```

[Если кто не в курсе о чем речь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1032103/%D0%A0%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8F%D0%B3%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8A%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B0-%D1%81%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%85%D1%83-%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B7)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Nike, у вас нет плавности поскольку `yield` задерживает на 0.1sec, а сдвигаете на `Time.deltaTime` (~0.0160.1sec при 60fps или ~0.030.1sec при 30fps) с неким множителем. Пишите это без использования `while` и `yield` в методе `void Update() {}`.

---

```
void Update () {
    Vector3 scale = transform.localScale;
    if (Vector3.Distance(rubber.position, cube.position)-1.5f > 0.5f) {
        rubber.transform.localPosition -= new Vector3(0, 7.8f * Time.deltaTime, 0);
        transform.localPosition = new Vector3(0, rubber.transform.localPosition.y, 0);
        scale.y += 0.002f * Time.deltaTime;
        transform.localScale = scale;
    }
}
```

Comment: Всегда помогаете мне, в трудную минуту, я сравнил 2 варианта, мне лучше показался, тот, который решается через `Animator`. Я запустил аниматор, двинул до конца мапы, после сделал расчет, если дистанция больше или равно, тормозим аниматор, когда все сделано делаем обратную анимацию и все прекрасно отрабатывает.

Comment: @Nike находчиво, но плохо. Воспользовался `Animator`, как костылями. От программирования не убежишь.

Comment: Дело в том, что резинка которая опускается она дергается сверху и не эстетично смотрится. То есть когда начинается опускаться игла и за ней резинка то сверху где резинка стыкуется с объектом от которого тянется она там дрыгается и просветы появляются. Как это устранить ?